# regex match domain name

Tags: python, regex

I have urls seems like this

https://inet.detik.com/cyberlife/d-4969020/jeff-bezos-jadi-orang-terkaya-sejagat-2020-bill-gates-kalah?tag_from=wp_beritautama&_ga=2.213088788.187118190.1586303591-856146141.1581847069

https://www.regexpal.com/?fam=93928

https://tekno.tempo.co/read/1329116/harimau-sumatera-ditemui-di-hutan-produksi-tapanuli-selatan

http://stackoverflow.com/posts/61091339/edit

how can i match these in regex :

inet.detik.com

www.regexpal.com

tekno.tempo.co

stackoverflow.com

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?
What doesn't work with your code and where is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use inbuilt regex in the library instead of writing your own.

In **Python3**

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
urlparse('https://www.regexpal.com/?fam=93928').netloc
```

Output:

```
'www.regexpal.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

`(https?:\/\/)([^\/]+)\/`

[Example matches](https://regex101.com/r/CVos0G/2)

Comment: In python, if you're using `re.search` it returns regex matches that have groups. So if you called match.group(2) you'd get just what's in the second set of parenthesis.